# Using Java SDK (AWS) to programmatically connect S3 to EC2 as a filesystem

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

### I am trying to use java sdk to create a local filesystem on an EC2 machine which would actually be a S3 resource

I have already written code to start EC2 machine, create security groups, keys etc but now want to mount a S3 on top of that EC2 machine that I create using java SDK. There seems to be no detailed solution online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should prepare your own AMI with s3fs pre-installed. See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=39361. The EC2 instance should be started from this custom AMI.

Second, right after the instance is up and running, you should establish an SSH connection to it and run

```
/usr/bin/s3fs bucketname /mnt/mountpoint
```

I would recommend to use [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)

Answer (score 0):

While there is a file system provider `s3fs` build on fuse. Is not always a good idea to try to mount it to the file system. Instead you should either use command line tools `s3cmd` or build in access to s3 into your filesystem.

The reason why I would recommend against it is that s3 is not a block device while the rest of your file system is. Everything on s3 is treated as a complete object. You can't read or write to a block of the object.

If all your are doing with the mount is copying files in its entirety to and from s3, a file system mount may work reasonably well. But you can't run anything that would expect block level acccess to files on that mount.